# How can I create and enforce contracts for exceptions?

Tags: c++, exceptions

I'm trying to convince my team lead to allow using exceptions in C++ instead of returning a bool `isSuccessful` or an enum with the error code. However, I can't counter this criticism of his.

Consider this library:

```
class OpenFileException() : public std::runtime_error {
}

void B();
void C();

/** Does blah and blah. */
void B() {
    // The developer of B() either forgot to handle C()'s exception or
    // chooses not to handle it and let it go up the stack.
    C();
};

/** Does blah blah.
 *
 * @raise OpenFileException When we failed to open the file. */
void C() {
    throw new OpenFileException();
};
```

1. Consider a developer calling the `B()` function. He checks its documentation and sees that it returns no exceptions, so he doesn't try to catch anything. This code could crash the program in production.
2. Consider a developer calling the `C()` function. He doesn't check the documentation so doesn't catch any exceptions. The call is unsafe and could crash the program in production.

But if we check for errors in this way:

```
void old_C(myenum &return_code);
```

A developer using that function will be warned by the compiler if he doesn't provide that argument, and he'd say "Aha, this returns an error code I must check for."

How can I use exceptions safely, so that there's some sort of contract?

Comment: How would you statically check whether the correct return_code is returned? And whether the returned return_code is enumerated in the comments? And whether it is handled by the caller? You cannot either, so this is not an argument in favor of return codes.

Comment: @Sjoerd The main advantage is that a developer is forced by the compiler to provide a variable to the function to store the return code; he is made aware that there can be an error and he should handle it. That is infinitely better than exceptions, which have no compile time checking at all.

Comment: "he should handle it" - there is no checking whether this happens either.

Comment: @Sjoerd It's not necessary. It's good enough to make the developer aware that an error can occur and that they should check for it. It's in the plain sight of the reviewers, too, whether they checked for an error or not.

Comment: Any decent C++ developer is aware that exceptions can occur.

Comment: You might have a better chance using an `Either`/`Result` monad to return the error in a type-safe composable way

Comment: @Dee: see `[[nodiscard]]` (C++17) as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327028/can-a-c-function-be-declared-such-that-the-return-value-cannot-be-ignored

Comment: If a developer uses C() without looking at the documentation the developer does not deserve success.

Comment: The formatting of the code block is off due to a missing `*/` but the edit is less than 6 characters so I can't fix it

Comment: @Daenyth I agree with your claim (I actually didn't know there was an `Either` type in C++), but people calling any type that happens to support a `bind` operation a monad is one of my pet peeves. It's not the `Either` monad, it's the `Either` *type* (constructor).

Comment: @gardenhead There's not one built in but you can write one. And fine, fine, let's say you use the `Either` type with monadic chaining for error handling? :P

Comment: @Daenyth I didn't know C++ had sum types at all! Wow, the times they are a-changing. Glad to hear it. And yes, I agree with that description :)

Comment: @gardenhead Here's an implementation https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/Expected.h

Comment: Considering how C++ exception system fails bad at catching issues at compile time, while a lot of modern C++ is very concerned about compile time validations and static type safety, not using exceptions (except for fatal issues where it is ok to have the program terminate) is quite valid guideline.

Comment: Despite being hated by so many people, this is the exact problem Java's checked exceptions solve: an exception that the compiler forces you to handle somewhere up the stack. If you don't handle it inside of `B()` when calling `C()`, then whoever calls `B()` must handle it or let it bubble further up the stack for someone else to handle, but in the end, someone MUST handle it.

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus I've always thought Java's checked exceptions were a wonderful approach, which is why it baffles me so much why no other languages have cribbed it. There must be some reason, but I'd like to know what that is. Heh, maybe I'll ask a new question on here!

Comment: @gardenhead Because too many developers don't use it properly, end up with ugly code, and proceed to blame the feature instead of themselves. The checked exception feature in Java is a beautiful thing, but it gets a bad rap because some people just don't get it.

Comment: C++ used to have [exception specifications](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec), but they were deprecated in C++11 in favour of [`noexcept`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec), partly because (IIRC) no compiler implemented static checking for specifications, and they had sometimes-surprising semantics—e.g., throwing an exception not in the specification would rethrow `std::bad_exception`.

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus Even with checked exception, you would be more interested in knowing how the caller can recover from the error. If the function implementation did use different exception types to communicate that validity of state (there may be different levels of validity) then all is fine. If checked exception is declared by a library's implementer then that is fine too - the caller can either heed the advice or ignore (log) it. But if the function that exposes checked exceptions didn't make any guarantee about validity of state, what good does it do? (Maybe a code example can explain.)

Comment: @gardenhead In java, checked exceptions break the ability to use abstraction and function composition. Contrast with Either, where both of those are extremely easy, and as a bonus can be implemented with library code rather than special language syntax

Comment: @Daenyth But you're comparing apples to oranges. Yes, exceptions are typically abused as a means to make up for the lack of `Either`/`Option`. But IMO exceptions and `Either` *should* serve two different purposes. There are some situations where an exception is more appropriate. They're just not very common.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**This is a legitimate criticism of exceptions.**  They are often less visible than simple error handling such as returning a code.  And there is no easy way to enforce a "contract".  Part of the point is to enable you to let exceptions be caught at a higher level (if you have to catch every exception at every level, how different is it from returning an error code, anyway?).  And this means that your code could be called by some other code that doesn't handle it appropriately.

**Exceptions do have downsides; you have to make a case based on cost-benefit.**
I found these two articles helpful: [The necessity of exceptions](https://mortoray.com/2012/03/08/the-necessity-of-exceptions/) and [Everything wrong with exceptions.](https://mortoray.com/2012/04/02/everything-wrong-with-exceptions/)  Also, [this blog post offers opinions of many experts on exceptions, with a focus on C++](http://www.codergears.com/Blog/?p=835).  While expert opinion seems to lean in favor of exceptions, it is far from a clear consensus.

As for convincing your team lead, **this might not be the right battle to pick.  Especially not with legacy code.** As noted in the second link above:

> Exceptions cannot be propagated through any code which is not
>   exception safe. The use of exceptions thus implies that all code in
>   the project must be exception safe.

Adding a little bit of code which uses exceptions to a project that mainly does not is probably *not* going to be an improvement.  Not using exceptions in otherwise well-written code is far from a catastrophic problem; it might not be a problem at all, depending on the application and which expert you ask.  You have to pick your battles.

This is probably not an argument I would spend effort on--at least not until a new project is started. And even if you have a new project, is it going to use or be used by any legacy code?

Comment: Thanks for the advice and the links. This is a new project, not a legacy one. I'm wondering why exceptions are so widespread when they have such a big drawback that makes their use unsafe. If you catch an exception n-levels higher, then later you modify the code and move it around, there's no static checking to guarantee the exception is still caught and handled (and it's too much to ask reviewers to check all functions n-levels deep).

Comment: @Dee see the links above for some arguments in favor of exceptions (I've added an additional link with more expert opinion).

Comment: This answer is spot on!

Comment: I can state from experience that trying to add exceptions to a pre-existing codebase is a REALLY bad idea. I've worked with such a codebase and it was REALLY, REALLY hard to work with because you never knew what was going to blow up in your face. Exceptions should ONLY be used in projects where you plan for them up front.

Answer (score 26):

*There are literally whole books written on this subject, so any answer will be a summary at best. Here are some of the important points I think are worth making, based on your question. It's not an exhaustive list.*

---

**Exceptions are intended NOT to be caught all over the place.**

As long as there is a general exception handler in the main loop - depending on the type of application (web server, local service, command line utility ...) - you usually have all the exception handlers you need.

In my code, there are only a few catch statements - if any at all - outside the main loop. And that seems to be the common approach in modern C++.

---

**Exceptions and return codes are not mutually exclusive.**

You should not make this an all-or-nothing approach. Exceptions should be used for exceptional situations. Things like "Config file not found," "Disk Full" or anything else that cannot be handled locally.

Common failures, like checking whether a filename provided by the user is valid, is not an use case for exceptions; Use a return value in those cases instead.

As you see from the above examples, "file not found" can be either an exception or a return code, depending on the use case: "is part of the installation" versus "user can make a typo."

So there is no absolute rule. A rough guideline is: *if it can be handled locally, make it a return value; if you cannot handle it locally, throw an exception.*

---

**Static checking of exceptions is not useful.**

As exceptions are not to be handled locally anyway, it usually isn't important which exceptions can be thrown. The only useful information is whether any exception can be thrown.

Java has static checking, but it usually is considered a failed experiment, and most languages since - notably C# - don't have that type of static checking. [This is a good read](http://www.artima.com/intv/handcuffs.html) about the reasons why C# doesn't have it.

For those reasons, C++ has deprecated its `throw(exceptionA, exceptionB)` in favor of `noexcept(true)`. The default is that a function can throw, so programmers should expect that unless the documentation explicitly promises otherwise.

---

**Writing exception safe code has nothing to do with writing exception handlers.**

I would rather say that writing exception safe code is all about how to avoid writing exception handlers!

Most of the best practices intend to reduce the number of exception handlers. Writing code once and automatically invoke it - e.g. through RAII - results in less bugs than copy-pasting the same code all over the place.

Comment: "*As long as there is a general exception handler...you are usually ok already.*"  This contradicts most sources, which stress that it is very challenging to write exception safe code.

Comment: @dan1111 "Writing exception safe code" has little to do with writing exception handlers. Writing exception safe code is about using RAII to encapsulate resources, using "do all work locally first then use swap/move," and other best practices. Those are challenging when you're not used to them. But "writing exception handlers" is not part of those best practices.

Comment: that is a fair point, but the question seems (to me, anyway) to be about exception safe code, more generally.

Comment: @dan1111 The "ok" doesn't mean "ok w.r.t. exception safe." It's ment to be "ok w.r.t. writing catch handlers." I'll clarify the text.

Comment: "Static checking of exceptions is not useful" - Umm, yes it is, in fact, it solves this exact problem. That some developers use it horribly when writing libraries is not a problem with the Java implementation, it's a problem with bad developers.

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus On some level, you can explain away every unsuccessful usage of a feature as "bad developers." The greatest ideas are the ones that *reduce bad usage* because they make doing the right thing simple. Statically checked exceptions do not fall in that category. They create work disproportionate to their value, often in places where the code being written simply does not even need to care about them. Users are tempted to silence them in wrong ways to make the compiler stop bothering them. Even done right, they lead to a lot of clutter.

Comment: @jpmc26 "They create work disproportionate to their value, often in places where the code being written simply does not even need to care about them" - In cases where the code being written does not need to care about them, all you need to do is add `throws XyzException` to the method signature, hardly any work in my opinion.

Comment: @jpmc26 "Users are tempted to silence them in wrong ways to make the compiler stop bothering them" - And those are the bad developers I'm talking about. If a developer does not appreciate the importance of handling the inevitable `IOException` from a network request, then that developer clearly needs to find a different profession. Features should encourage good behavior, not bad ones.

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus The reason that it is disproportionate is that this can easily propagate to *nearly every function in your entire code base*. When all the functions in half my classes access the database, not every one of them needs to explicitly declare it can throw a SQLException; neither does every controller method that calls them. That much noise is actually a negative value, regardless of how small the amount of work is. Sjoerd hits the nail on the head: *most of your code does not need to be concerned with exceptions because it can't do anything about them anyway*.

Comment: It's too bad languages lack convenient syntax that would indicate "Let me know if an exception occurs, but don't pretend you're going to resolve it", and "If an exception occurs, wrap and rethrow as something derived from 'UnexpectedException'".  In many cases, such actions would be more appropriate than catching exceptions or letting them bubble up the stack.

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus Also consider the principle of composition over inheritance. Are you going to declare that every function that calls an arbitrary class' functions can throw a general exception? If you don't, then you can't write an implementation for your other class to throw the exception. Now you're back to being tempted to catch something your shouldn't so you can pass your class into the other one.

Comment: @jpmc26 "this can easily propagate to nearly every function in your entire code base" - that's a horrendous exaggeration. If you're opening a network connection, only some of the methods in the stack concerned with that task will ever have the word `IOException` in them. In my years of experience developing in Java, have I never had to add `throws XyzException` to more than one or two methods in any given stack.

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus Then you must have lots of undeclared `RuntimeException` cases all over your code. =) Like all the `NullPointerException`s and `IllegalArgumentException`s you didn't declare. So your position is already shot.

Comment: @jpmc26 `NullPointerException`s and `IllegalArgumentException`s, (both of which inherit from `RuntimeException`) are NOT checked exceptions. You don't have to declare them, and that's perfectly fine, because the client doesn't need to handle them. If you get a `NullPointerException`, don't handle it, fix your code so that it doesn't throw it in the first place. That's the difference between a checked and an unchecked exception.

Comment: @jpmc26 You don't handle `NullPointerException`s, you fix your code so that it doesn't get thrown in the first place; unlike `IOException`s which get thrown due to factors out of your control (like a network hiccup), if you're a decent developer, then you know that you MUST handle that `IOException`, and Java helps you make sure you do, that's a good thing.

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus Yes, because the best developers are so perfect their code will always handle every single possible user input perfectly, and you will *never, ever, ever* see those exceptions in prod. And if you do, it means you are a failure at life. Seriously, don't give me this garbage. Nobody is that perfect, not even the best. And your app should behave sanely even in the face of those errors, even if "sanely" is "stop and return a half decent error page/message". And guess what: *that's the same thing you do with 99% of `IOException`s, too*. The checked division is arbitrary and useless.

Comment: @jpmc26 It doesn't matter, you still don't have to declare those exceptions in Java, so that point that you made about me not declaring exceptions all over the place, and that checked exceptions make the code too convoluted is still moot. And the check division is not arbitrary or useless, I already explained why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47619/discussion-between-jpmc26-and-axiomaticnexus).

Answer (score 8):

**C++ programmers don't look for exception specifications. They look for exception guarantees.**

Suppose a piece of code did throw an exception. What assumptions can the programmer make that will still be valid? From the way the code is written, what does the code guarantee in the aftermath of an exception?

Or is it possible that a certain piece of code can guarantee never to throw (i.e. nothing short of the OS process being terminated)?

The word "roll back" occurs frequently in discussions about exceptions. Being able to roll back to a valid state (that is explicitly documented) is an example of exception guarantee. If there is no exception guarantee, a program should be terminating on the spot because it is not even guaranteed that any code it executes thereafter will work as intended - say, if memory has corrupted, any further operation is technically undefined behavior.

Various C++ programming techniques promote exception guarantees. RAII (scope-based resource management) provides a mechanism to execute cleanup code and ensure that resources are released in both normal cases and exceptional cases. Making a copy of data before performing modifications on objects allow one to restore that object's state if the operation fails. And so on.

The answers to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853243/c-do-you-really-write-exception-safe-code) gives a glimpse to the great lengths C++ programmers go to understand all of the possible failure modes that could happen to their code and try to guard the validity of program state despite failures. Line-by-line analysis of C++ code becomes a habit.

When developing in C++ (for production use), one cannot afford to gloss over the details. Also, binary blob (non-open-source) is the bane of C++ programmers. If I have to call some binary blob, and the blob fails, then reverse engineering is what a C++ programmer would do next.

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/exceptions#Exception_safety - see under Exception Safety.

**C++ had a failed attempt at implementing exception specifications. Later analysis in other languages says that exception specifications simply aren't practical.**

Why it is a failed attempt: to enforce it strictly, it has to be part of the type system. But it isn't. The compiler does not check for exception specification.

Why C++ chose that, and why experiences from other languages (Java) proves that exception specification is moot: As one modify the implementation of a function (for example, it needs to make a call to a different function that may throw a new kind of exception), a strict exception specification enforcement means you have to update that specification as well. This propagates - you may end up having to update the  exception specifications for dozens or hundreds of functions for what is a simple change. Things get worse for abstract base classes (the C++ equivalent of interfaces). If exception specification is enforced on interfaces, implementations of interfaces will not be allowed to call functions that throw different types of exceptions.

Reference: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm

Starting with C++17, the `[[nodiscard]]` attribute can be used on function return values (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327028/can-a-c-function-be-declared-such-that-the-return-value-cannot-be-ignored).

**So if I make a code change and that introduces a new kind of failure condition (i.e. a new type of exception), is it a breaking change? Should it have compelled the caller to update the code, or at least be warned about the change?**

If you accept the arguments that C++ programmers look for exception guarantees instead of exception specifications, then the answer is that if the new kind of failure condition doesn't break any of the exception guarantees the code previously promises, it is not a breaking change.

Comment: "As one modify the implementation of a function (for example, it needs to make a call to a different function that may throw a new kind of exception), a strict exception specification enforcement means you have to update that specification as well" - Good, as you should. What would be the alternative? Ignoring the newly introduced exception?

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus That is also answered by exception guarantee. In fact I argue specification can never be complete; guarantee is what we look for. Often, we compare the exception type in an attempt to find out what guarantee was broken - in order to guess at what guarantee was still valid. Exception specification lists some of the types you need to check, but remember that in any practical system, the list cannot be possibly complete. Most of the time, it forces people to take the shortcut of "eating" the exception type, wrapping it in another exception, which makes exception type checking hard

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus I am neither arguing for or against the use of exception. Typical exception usage encourages having a base exception class and some derived exception classes. Meanwhile, one has to remember that other exception types are possible, e.g. those thrown from C++ STL or other libraries. It could be argued that exception specification could be made to work in this case: specify that the standard exceptions (`std::exception`) and your own base exception will be thrown. But when applied to a whole project, it simply means every single function will have this same specification: noise.

Comment: I would point out that when it comes to exceptions, C++ and Java / C# are different languages. Firstly C++ isn't type-safe in the sense of allowing arbitrary code execution or data overwrite, secondly C++ doesn't print a nice stack trace. These differences forced C++ programmers to make different choices in terms of error and exception handling. It also means that certain projects could legitimately claim that C++ isn't a suitable language for them. (For example, I personally consider that TIFF image decoding shall not be permitted to be implemented in C or C++.)

Comment: @rwong: A big problem with exception handling in languages which follow the C++ model is that `catch` is based upon the *type* of the exception object, when in many cases what matters is not so much the direct cause of the exception but rather what it implies about the system state.  Unfortunately, the type of an exception generally says nothing about whether it caused code to disruptively exit a piece of code in a way that left an object in a partially-updated (and thus invalid) state.

Answer (score 4):

> Consider a developer calling the C() function. He doesn't check the
>   documentation so doesn't catch any exceptions. The call is unsafe

It's totally safe. He doesn't need to catch exceptions in every place, he can just throw a try/catch in a place where he can actually do something useful about it. It's only unsafe if he allows it to leak out of a thread, but it's typically not hard to prevent that from happening.

Comment: It is unsafe since he doesn't expect an exception coming out of `C()`, and consequently does not safeguard against the code following the call being skipped. If that code is required to guarantee that some invariance remains true, that guarantee goes poof at the first exception coming out of `C()`. There is no such thing as perfectly exception-safe software, and most certainly not where exceptions were never expected.

Comment: @cmaster *Him not expecting an exception coming out of `C()`* is a big mistake. The default in C++ is that any function can throw - it requires an explicit `noexcept(true)` to tell the compiler otherwise. In absence of this promise, a programmer must assume that a function can throw.

Comment: @cmaster That is his own dumb fault and nothing to do with the author of C(). Exception safety is a thing, he should learn about it, and follow it. If he calls a function he doesn't know is noexcept, he should damn well handle what happens if it throws. If he needs noexcept, he should find an implementation which is.

Comment: @Sjoerd and DeadMG: While the standard allows any function to throw an exception, that does not mean that projects must allow exceptions in their code. If you ban exceptions from your code, just like the OP's team-lead seems to be doing, you don't have to do exception-safe programming. And if you try to convince a team-lead to allow exceptions into a code base that was previously exception free, there will be a ton of `C()` functions that break in the presence of exceptions. This is really a very unwise thing to do, it is doomed to lead to a ton of problems.

Comment: @cmaster This is about a new project - see the first comment on the accepted answer. So there are no existing functions that will break, as there are no existing functions.

Comment: @Sjoerd Ah, I didn't see that comment. In that case, the "only" threat to the safety of calling `C()` is indeed developer error. Nevertheless, developers are sloppy, so the fact remains that any call of `C()` is inherently unsafe unless someone has explicitly checked the control flow resulting from an exception coming out of `C()`. And I don't know a single developer whom I would trust performing that check on every function call they write.

Comment: @cmaster A single `catch(..)` in the main loop and in each thread's start function guarantees that the exception will be caught. There is no need to check that over and over again for each function.

Comment: @Sjoerd It guarantees that the exceptions are caught, but it does nothing to guarantee data consistency. Data consistency must be ensured by a developer considering the relevant control flow. And if the developers fail to perform these checks (= source code reading and analysis), your process is carrying on with inconsistent data if it just catches all exceptions at the top layer.

Comment: @cmaster Data consistency is achieved by programming using best practices regarding exception guarantees. Those best practices have been known for about 20 years now: "Exceptional C++" by Herb Sutter was published in 1999.

Answer (score 3):

If you are building a critical system, consider following your team lead's advice and not use exceptions. This is AV Rule 208 in [Lockheed Martin's Joint Strike Fighter Air Vehicle C++ Coding Standards](http://www.stroustrup.com/JSF-AV-rules.pdf). On the other hand, [MISRA](https://www.misra.org.uk/) C++ guidelines have very specific rules regarding when exceptions can and cannot be used if you are building a MISRA-compliant software system.

If you are building critical systems, chances are you are also running static analysis tools. Many static analysis tools will warn if you do not check the return value of a method, making cases of missing error handling readily apparent. To the best of my knowledge, similar tool support for detecting proper exception handling is not as strong.

Ultimately, I would argue that [design by contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) and defensive programming, coupled with static analysis is safer for critical software systems than exceptions.